# Is there a simple way in Swift 5.7 to get a regular expression that ignores diacritics when matching?

Tags: swift

Swift 5.7 introduces a lot of improvements for regular expressions, including a `.ignoresCase()` function to ignore casing when matching.

```
"Lorem IPSUM dolor.".contains(/ipsum/.ignoresCase()) // true
```

I didn't find any equivalent `ignoresDiacritic()` function. Do you know why? Is it recommended to remove the diacritic from the string first? And if so, which of these two methods is better?

```
"Lorem ÏPSÛM dolor."
    .applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!
    .contains(/ipsum/.ignoresCase()) // true

"Lorem ÏPSÛM dolor."
    .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
    .contains(/ipsum/.ignoresCase()) // true
```

Comment: Reading through the documentation, it doesn't look like there's an option for `Regex` that does this, yet. It sure sounds like a useful addition, so how about filing a Feedback with Apple to make them aware of this?